# Alternative mode to TalkBack for blind users: better support for blindness?

Tags: accessibility, talk-back

I was wondering about a question I raised in another post about accessibility. That is, how would an app provide a separate interface for blind users? The Android system, would have to support a special feature, "navigate in blind mode". Android already has TalkBack, but that is designed to explore apps in their standard layout, a layout that may not always be completely accessible or convenient for blind users, who might require or get more benefit from something else.

How does Android provide support, if any, for this. Is there a switch for blind and non blind mode which does not end up in being TalkBack, that can be used?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with this post? Why, is it being deleted?

Comment: I don't see any indicator that this question has been deleted. Did you mean your older questions? If yes, then there's [Roomba](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) that deletes old unanswered questions automatically.